# How to auto-upload files to google drive?

Tags: google-drive

lets say I have a working directory, and want to upload (only upload!) files when they changes. This is a backup, so Im the only one who could see them. How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you install the Google Drive program? There are instructions for syncing [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374992?hl=en).

Comment: @MC10 I think John wants to upload files *only*, not sync.

Comment: I suppose this would not be a good option for backups if modifications were made on the Google Drive end. I haven't seen an "auto upload" feature outside of photos and videos so I suggest waiting for someone to post a real answer if one exists.